# Exercise 2.3.5 in Vershynin's HDP book

Tags: probability, inequality

Let $X_i$ be independent Bernoulli random variables with parameters $p_i$. Consider their sum $S_N=\sum_{i=1}^N X_i$ and denote its mean by $\mu=\mathsf{E} S_N$. Then, for $\delta\in (0,1]$, prove that
$$\mathsf{P}\{|S_N-\mu|\geqslant \delta\mu\}\leqslant 2e^{-c\mu\delta^2}$$
where $c>0$ is an absolute constant.

This is the Exercise 2.3.5 in Vershynin's HDP book. My idea and problem are as following:

============================  **My Solution** ============================

I use the following two inequalities:

1.[Chenoff's inequality] $$\mathsf{P}\{S_N\geqslant t\}\leqslant e^{-\mu}\left(\frac{e\mu}{t}\right)^t,\qquad (t>\mu)$$
2.[Extension of Chernoff's inequality, see Exercise 2.3.2 in Vershynin's HDP book] $$\mathsf{P}\{S_N\leqslant t\}\leqslant e^{-\mu}\left(\frac{e\mu}{t}\right)^t,\qquad (t<\mu)$$

Then I get
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathsf{P}\{|S_N-\mu|\geqslant \delta\mu\}&\leqslant \mathsf{P}\{S_N-\mu\geqslant \delta\mu\} + \mathsf{P}\{\mu-S_N\geqslant \delta\mu\}\\[0.5em]
&=\mathsf{P}\{S_N\geqslant (1+\delta)\mu\}+\mathsf{P}\{S_N\leqslant (1-\delta)\mu\}\\[1em]
&\leqslant e^{-\mu} \left\{\left(\frac{e}{1+\delta}\right)^{(1+\delta)\mu}+\left(\frac{e}{1-\delta}\right)^{(1-\delta)\mu}\right\}.\qquad[\text{use ineq. 1 & 2 above}]
\end{aligned}
$$

============================ **My Problem** ============================
However, I cannot prove that
$$
e^{-\mu} \left\{\left(\frac{e}{1+\delta}\right)^{(1+\delta)\mu}+\left(\frac{e}{1-\delta}\right)^{(1-\delta)\mu}\right\} \leqslant 2e^{-c\mu\delta^2}.\tag{*}
$$
Is the ineq. (*) true?

Answer (score 9):

It can help to write down the desired inequality and work backwards.
\begin{align}
e^{-\mu} (e/(1+\delta))^{(1+\delta)\mu}
&\le e^{-c \mu \delta^2}
\\
\delta + c \delta^2
& \le (1+\delta) \log(1+\delta)
& \text{take logarithms, rearrange}
\end{align}
Use Taylor's theorem to approximate $\log(1+\delta)$ with $\delta + c' \delta^2$.

The other inequality $e^{-\mu} (e/(1-\delta))^{(1-\delta)\mu} \le e^{-c\mu \delta^2}$ can be handled similarly.