# Solving exercise 2.3.5 in Vershynin's HDP book with the best choice of c

Tags: probability, inequality

I am starting to work my way through Vershynin's *High-Dimensional Probability* and have become stuck on Exercise 2.3.5.  The problem is as follows: Let $X_i \sim \text{Bern}(p_i)$ ($i\in\{1,\dots,N\}$) be independent.  Denote $S_N := \sum_i X_i$ and $\mu := ES_N$.  Then show that there is some absolute constant $c>0$ such that for all $\delta\in (0,1]$, we have
$$P(|S_N-\mu|\geq \delta\mu)\leq 2\exp(-c\mu\delta^2).$$
I have applied Chernoff's inequality to transform the problem into showing the following inequality:
$$\left(\frac{e}{1+\delta}\right)^{1+\delta} + \left(\frac{e}{1-\delta}\right)^{1-\delta} \leq 2\exp(1-c\delta^2).$$
Following a process similar to the hint given by the answer to [this Math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3833114/exercise-2-3-5-in-vershynins-hdp-book), I've shown the inequality for some $c<\frac{1}{2}$.  However, the approach given there requires one to bound each term on the lefthand side by half the righthand side; I think that this loses some efficiency, since one needs to choose one choice of $c$ to bound each term separately even though they are unequal.  Indeed, when I try to bound each term separately I can't use $c=1/2$, but from plotting the functions I see that $c=1/2$ should work (and it seems that the bound does not hold for $c>1/2$, so this is the best choice of $c$).  Does anyone have a hint (or several) for solving the problem with $c=1/2$?

Comment: An interesting finding is that the coefficients of the Taylor expansion of$$\frac{\exp\left(-x+\frac{x^2}2\right)}{(1-x)^{1-x}}=\exp\left(-\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n(n-1)}\right)$$at $x=0$ are all nonpositive (except for the constant term), which is sufficient for proving the inequaliy with $c=\frac12$.

Answer (score 1):

That $c=1/2$ is the largest $c$ to make the inequality true can be seen by the Taylor expansions of both sides. I will do that at 0 up to order 4. To save some typing, I will write $x$ for $\delta$. Note that both sides are even functions of $x$, so we would only have even powers of $x$.
We want to show that
\begin{align}
\big(\frac{e}{1+x}\big)^{1+x} + \big(\frac{e}{1-x}\big)^{1-x} &= 2e\big(1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}\big)+O(x^6),\\
2e^{1-cx^2}&=2e\big(1-cx^2 + \frac{c^2}{2}x^4\big)+ O(x^6).
\end{align}
The second one is very easy, and it follows from $e^{1-cx^2}=e\cdot e^{-cx^2}$ and the standard MacLaurin series for $e^x$. So if we establish the first one, then $c=1/2$ is the largest $c$ for the equality to hold, and it does indeed hold since then the coefficients for $x^4$ are $\frac{c^2}2=\frac18>\frac1{24}$.

To establish the first expansion, we use the standard series
$$
\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3-\frac{x^4}4+O(x^5),
$$
to compute everything up to order $4$. But note that by the evenness of the function, the next term would be $O(x^6)$. We compute
\begin{align}
\big(\frac{e}{1+x}\big)^{1+x} &= e^{1+x}\cdot e^{-(1+x)\ln(1+x)}\\
&=e^{(1+x)(1-\ln(1+x))}\\
&=e^{(1+x)(1-x+\frac{x^2}2-\frac{x^3}3+\frac{x^4}4+\dots)}\\
&=e^{1-\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{6} - \frac{x^4}{12} +\dots}\\
&=e\big(1-\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{6} - \frac{x^4}{12} + \frac{1}{2}(-\frac{x^2}{2})^2+\dots\big)\\
&=e\big(1-\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{6}+(\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{12})x^4+\dots\big)\\
&=e\big(1-\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{1}{24}x^4+\dots\big).
\end{align}
A similar calculation gives
$$
\big(\frac{e}{1-x}\big)^{1-x} = e\big(1-\frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{1}{24}x^4+\dots\big).
$$
Adding these two, we get our first expansion.