# Proving $e^{-\mu}\left(\left(\frac{e}{1+\delta}\right)^{(1+\delta)\mu}+\left(\frac{e}{1-\delta}\right)^{(1-\delta)\mu}\right) \le 2e^{-C\mu\delta^2}$

Tags: analysis, proof-explanation

I'm trying to show that
$$e^{-\mu}\left(\left(\frac{e}{1+\delta}\right)^{(1+\delta)\mu} + \left(\frac{e}{1-\delta}\right)^{(1-\delta)\mu}\right) \le 2e^{-C\mu\delta^2},$$
for an absolute constant $C > 0$, where $\delta \in (0,1]$ and $\mu > 0$.

Using the idea in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3833114/exercise-2-3-5-in-vershynins-hdp-book), I wrote
$$\log(1+\delta) = 0 + \delta \frac{1}{1+0} - \frac{\delta^2}{(1+\delta')^2},$$
for some $\delta' \in (0, \delta).$ This gives $(1+\delta')^2 \le 4$, i.e., $- \frac{\delta^2}{(1+\delta')^2} \le -\frac{\delta^2}{4}$. Plugging back in, we have the upper bound
$$\log(1+\delta) = \delta - \frac{\delta^2}{(1+\delta')^2} \le \delta - \frac{\delta^2}{4}.$$
This doesn't immediately seem helpful, since we are looking for a bound of the form $$\log(1+\delta) \ge \frac{\delta + C\delta^2}{1+ \delta},$$
i.e., a lower bound. Could I get a hint? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Why not using:

$$\frac{e}{1+\delta} \ge 1 \implies \left(\frac{e}{1+\delta}\right)^{\mu (1-\delta)} \le \left(\frac{e}{1+\delta}\right)^{\mu (1+\delta)}$$

and use the inequality from the other question.

---

If you want to expand the other question: use the fact that $1+\delta' \ge 1$

Comment: Which inequality from the other question? I believe I am asking for a proof of the same, in particular, details about the proof sketch in the answer.

Comment: The inequality is not the same. The exponent there is $(1+\delta)\mu$ instead of $(1-\delta)\mu$

Comment: Sorry there was a typo!

Answer (score 1):

I will show that any
$0 < c < \dfrac13$
will do.

Start with
$\dfrac{1-x^n}{1-x}
=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k
$,
so
$\dfrac1{1-x}
=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k+\dfrac{x^n}{1-x}
$
or,
putting $-x$ for $x$,
$\dfrac1{1+x}
=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^kx^k+\dfrac{(-1)^nx^n}{1+x}
$.

Integrating from
$0$ to $x$
(assuming $0 < x < 1$, and replacing $x$ by $t$
in the integrand),

$\begin{array}\\
\ln(1+x)
&=\int_0^x \dfrac{dt}{1+t}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^k\int_0^x t^kdt+(-1)^n\int_0^x \dfrac{t^n dt}{1+t}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^k\dfrac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}+(-1)^n e_n(x)\\
\end{array}
$

where
$e_n(x)
=\int_0^x \dfrac{t^n dt}{1+t}
\gt 0$
and
$e_n(x)
\gt e_{n+1}(x)
$.

We also have

$\begin{array}\\
e_n(x)
&=\int_0^x \dfrac{t^n dt}{1+t}\\
&<\int_0^x t^n dt\\
&=\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\\
\text{and}\\
e_n(x)
&=\int_0^x \dfrac{t^n dt}{1+t}\\
&>\dfrac1{1+x}\int_0^x t^n dt\\
&=\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)(1+x)}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
for $n=2$,
$\ln(1+x)
\lt x-\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{x^3}{3}
$
and
$\ln(1+x)
\gt x-\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{x^3}{3(1+x)}
$.

From this last,
we get the desired inequality if
$$x-\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{x^3}{3(1+x)}
\ge \dfrac{x+cx^2}{1+x}
$$
or,
multiplying by
$6(1+x)$,
$$6x(1+x)-3x^2(1+x)+2x^3
\ge 6(x+cx^2)\
$$
or
$$6x+6x^2-3x^2-3x^3+2x^3
\ge 6x+6cx^2\
$$
or
$$6x+3x^2-x^3
\gt 6x+6cx^2\
$$
or
$$3-x \ge 6c
$$
or
$$c
\le \dfrac12-\dfrac{x}{6}.
$$
Since
$0 < x < 1$,
$c < \dfrac13$
will do.